# superlative and "elative": What is "Elativ" in English?

Tags: grammar

I always forget that "elative" is no grammar term in English.

In Latin grammars (at least in German ones) "Elativ" is a superlative form that is not translated as superlative but
with "very/highly", expressing a high degree but not the absolutely highest degree.

What is the English term for an expression such as:
- a most interesting novel

Comment: This is also called elative in English.

Comment: By a few people, perhaps. Most educated English speakers wouldn't understand the term, and would probably also be pretty unclear about positive, comparative, and superlative.

Comment: @JohnLawler, of course! Just like most educated German speakers wouldn't understand the word "Elativ".

Comment: @rhuffstedtler, "elative" is pretty common in linguistic typology. References? How about this one http://books.google.com/books?id=Kl-Nlc7toDQC&lpg=PP1&ots=0lZQoTmwyG&dq=Cognitive%20Foundations%20of%20Grammar&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q=Cognitive%20Foundations%20of%20Grammar&f=false?

Comment: @Alex B- just as an interesting note, the table 6-1 on page 109 of your reference is missing the opposite of Excessive which I might call "Insufficient"- i.e., David is not smart enough.

Answer (score 1):

I have typically seen "most" in your example labeled as an intensifier in English grammar. It's functioning as a grammatical expletive rather than as a true superlative.

Alex B. - do you have a reference for that being called an elative in English? I was not able to find one.

Comment: You comment to Alex should be a comment in the main item, not in your answer.